# Add new column to HTML table which has not table id

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

How can i get to add a new column in the below code,
I need this to happen if there is no table id or tr id or td id.

Please check and tell me

```
<p>Click the button to insert new cell(s) at the beginning of the table row.</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First cell</td>
    <td>Second cell</td>
    <td>Third cell</td>
  </tr>
</table><br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var row = ??????????????
    var x = row.insertCell(0);
    x.innerHTML = "New cell";
}
</script>
```

Comment: So you just want to get a reference to any table without an id, or to any tr without an id, or to any td without an id? That would be every element in that table in that example--is that right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` for access your tables.

```
var row = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows[0];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4rmt4xmj/1/

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @a.u.b using `var row = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows[0];` is good but I'd like to mention an alternative approach using `XPath`.

You can inspect-element and then select that table and right-click -> Copy -> **Copy XPath**

Then you can use the following code to obtain the desired element:

```
var elementTable = document.evaluate( '/html/body/table' ,document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue;
if (elementTable != null) {
  //do something
}
```

Here's the [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4yzm54no/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
    function myFunction(){
     var row = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows[0];
     var x = row.insertCell();
     x.innerHTML = "Last";
    }
```

```html
 <table border="1">
   <tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>Third</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <br /><br />
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```